# Attempted to load class from namespace. Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace? with vendor php namespace

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to load a php namespace into my symfony project but keep getting the following error at runtime.

```
Attempted to load class "FM" from namespace "VehicleTracking\Src\Vendors\FM".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
```

The controller that it is being called from

```
namespace BWT\FMBundle\Controller;

use VehicleTracking\Src\Vendors\FM\FM;

class FMController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @Route("/fuel_data", name="fuelData")
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function fuelDataAction(Request $request)
    {
        //...
        $tripProcesses = new FM(); //<-this is the line where I get the error
        $_results = $tripProcesses->getTripWithTotals($form->get('fleetNo')->getData(), $form->get('startDate')->getData(), $form->get('endDate')->getData());
    }
}
```

The FM.php file. which is in the directory vendor/bwt/vehicle_tracking/src/vendors
tracking.interface and tracking.class are in the same directory

```
<?php
namespace VehicleTracking\Src\Vendors\FM;
// : Includes
include_once (dirname(realpath(__FILE__)) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .    'tracking.interface');
include_once (dirname(realpath(__FILE__)) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'tracking.class');
// : End
use VehicleTracking\Src\Vendors\Vendors as Vendors;
use VehicleTracking\Src\Vendors\TrackingInterface as TrackingInterface;

class FM extends Vendors\Vendors implements TrackingInterface\TrackingInterface
{
    public function getTrackingData()
    {...}
}
```

autoload_namespace.php

```
 <?php

// autoload_namespaces.php @generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    //...
    '' => array($vendorDir . '/bwt/vehicle_tracking/src/vendors'),
);
```

Comment: How about to make it like the second code block `use VehicleTracking\Src\Vendors\FM as FM;`  later `new FM\FM();`. Is that an sympony error message? What did the error wants to tell you? Was the class not found?

Comment: Did you somehow try to install the package manually because your autoload_namespace file should be something like: 'VehicleTracking\\Src\\Vendors\\ => array(...  Is this your own package?  If so then I suspect the composer.json needs some work.

Comment: In the `FM.php` file did you tried to use the namespace `namespace Vendor\Bwt\VehicleTracking\Src\Vendors` (without the last `FM`)? Because your directory structure is `vendor/bwt/vehicle_tracking/src/vendors`.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions I've tried that and getting the same error.

Comment: @Cerad I installed it through composer but had to edit the autoload_namespace file manuqally. I know the developer of the package so I can ask him to do some changes it's composer.json. Do you know what changes need to be made?

Comment: @DanCostinel I've trid that and get the same errors

Comment: Your FM class have the namespace as `VehicleTracking\Src\Vendors` ( remove the last Fm) and import this namespace as `import VehicleTracking\Src\Vendors\Fm`.

Comment: @DanCostinel still getting the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We eventually solved this by adding

```
"autoload" : {
    "psr-4" : {
        "Vendors\\" : "src/"
    }
},
```

to the composer.json of the external package and changed the namespace of the classes to `namespace Vendors;` so that it would be the same as the directory.

I have to run `composer update -o` to optimise the autoloader otherwise I keep getting these errors.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule you should avoid editing anything under vendor.  Your changes will be lost.  In this case you can edit your projects composer.json file

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": "src/",
        "VehicleTracking\\Src\\Vendors\\FM\\": "vendor/bwt/vehicle_tracking/src/vendors"
    },
```

After making changes, run composer dump-autoload to update the autoload stuff.

The path I gave is based on your question, at least that was the intent.  It assumes that FM.php is located directly under vendor/bwt/vehicle_tracking/src/vendors

I only tested a fake FM.php class.  That fact that there are include statements in there and some other strange code might generate additional errors.

Comment: still getting the same error, even after clearing the cache. Yes, the FM.php file is directly in the vendor/bwt/vehicle_tracking/src/vendors directory.

Comment: I know the developer of the package and can ask him to make changes to his composer.json file.

Comment: Hopefully adjusting composer.json will help but if you are still getting the exact same error then you have something else wrong.  I tested what I posted so I know it works.  You probably have a typo somewhere.